# Как найти свободный порт?

Tags: winapi, delphi, порт

Нужно найти свободный порт либо функциями Delphi либо функциями WINAPI.
UPD1. U-Boot коннектится к TFTP серверу чтобы скачать ядро Linux. Программа конфигуратор выступает в качестве сервера, так что она знает про порт и скажет его U-boot. 
Проблему решили средствами Delphi. Всем спасибо.

Comment: В смысле, TCP порт? :) Свободный входящий порт, чтобы его слушать?

Comment: Зачем это делать? Если вы хотите его слушать, то кто тогда сможет на него подключиться, если никто не знает, куда коннектиться? А если вы подключаетесь, то ничего не надо делать, система сама выберет какой-нибудь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще средствами голого WinAPI работать с TCP… эээ… нуу… Может, всё же, сокеты?

Тогда я не понимаю в чём проблема. Создавать слушающий сокет на каком-то порту, если не получилось, то создавать на другом. В цикле либо по набору красивых портов, либо просто начиная с какого-то числа единичку прибавлять.

Comment: Так и сделали :-D

Answer (score 1):

Так и не понял, зачем нужно искать свободный TCP порт, но, если все же хотите извращений, используйте функцию GetTcpTable (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366026(VS.85).aspx). Она вернет список всех TCP соединений машины.

Answer (score 0):

Когда-то писал такую ​​прогу ... правда, по примеру.

```
unit AdrPortScanner;

interface

uses
  Classes,SysUtils,WinSock,AppEvnts,Windows,Forms,Messages;

type
  // Найден открытый порт
  TPortExistsEvent = procedure (Sender:TObject; Port:Integer) of object;
  // Начало проверки
  TWorkBeginEvent = procedure (Sender:TObject; Min,Max:integer) of object;

  TPortScanner = class abstract
  private
    FIPAddress: AnsiString;
    //FOnPortChecking: TPortExistsEvent;
    //FOnCheckingDone: TNotifyEvent;
    FOnPortExists: TPortExistsEvent;
    FOnWork: TPortExistsEvent;
    FOnWorkBegin: TWorkBeginEvent;
    FOnWorkEnd: TNotifyEvent;
    FTerminated: boolean;
    FTimeOut: Word;
    FPortStart: Word;
    FPortEnd: Word;
  protected
    FWorking: boolean;
    FMaxOpenPort: Word;
    procedure SetMaxOpenPort(const Value: Word);  virtual; abstract;
  public
    constructor Create;

    // Можно запустить, указав URI и в ответ получить существует ли такой
    function  StartChecking(const URI:string):boolean;  overload;
    // А можно указать IP через свойство и просто запустить проверку
    procedure StartChecking;                    overload; virtual; abstract;
    procedure Terminate;

    property IPAddress:AnsiString   read  FIPAddress  write FIPAddress;
    property MaxOpenPort:Word read FMaxOpenPort write SetMaxOpenPort;
    property PortStart:Word  read  FPortStart  write FPortStart;
    property PortEnd:Word  read  FPortEnd  write FPortEnd;
    property Terminated:boolean read FTerminated write FTerminated;
    property TimeOut:Word  read  FTimeOut  write FTimeOut;
    property Working:boolean read FWorking;  // ...проверка продолжается?

    property OnWork:TPortExistsEvent read FOnWork write FOnWork;
    property OnWorkBegin:TWorkBeginEvent read FOnWorkBegin write FOnWorkBegin;
    property OnWorkEnd:TNotifyEvent read FOnWorkEnd write FOnWorkEnd;
    property OnPortExists:TPortExistsEvent read FOnPortExists
        write FOnPortExists;
  end;

//==============================================================================

  TPortScanner1 = class (TPortScanner)
  type
    TFSocket = record
      sa: TSockAddr;
      FData: integer;
      ATimeOut: word;
    end;

  private
    FSocket: array of TFSocket;
    FPort: WORD;
    FInfo: TWSADATA;
    FHost: integer;
    FWorking:boolean;
    FTerminated:boolean;

    procedure InitSockets;
    procedure ApplicationEventsMessage(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
    procedure Checking;
  protected
    procedure SetMaxOpenPort(const Value: Word); override;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy;   override;

    procedure StartChecking;  override;
  end;

  function getIPFromHost(const HostName: AnsiString): AnsiString;

implementation//****************************************************************

function GetIPFromHost(const HostName: Ansistring): AnsiString;
type
  TaPInAddr = array[0..10] of PInAddr;
  PaPInAddr = ^TaPInAddr;
var
  phe: PHostEnt;
  pptr: PaPInAddr;
  i: Integer;
  GInitData: TWSAData;
begin
  WSAStartup($101, GInitData);
  Result := '';
  phe := GetHostByName(PAnsiChar(HostName));
  if phe = nil then Exit;
  pPtr := PaPInAddr(phe^.h_addr_list);
  i := 0;
  while pPtr^[i] <> nil do
  begin
    Result := inet_ntoa(pptr^[i]^);
    Inc(i);
  end;
  WSACleanup;
end;

{ TPortScanner1 }

procedure TPortScanner1.ApplicationEventsMessage(var Msg: tagMSG;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if (Msg.message>=FPortStart+WM_USER)
                                and (Msg.message<=FPortEnd+WM_USER)
  then
  if WSAGETSELECTERROR(Msg.lParam)=0
  then
    case WSAGETSELECTEVENT(msg.lParam) of
      FD_CONNECT:
        begin
          if Assigned(OnPortExists) then
            OnPortExists(Self,Msg.message - WM_USER);
          Application.ProcessMessages;
        end;
    end;
  Handled:=false;
end;

procedure TPortScanner1.Checking;
var
 i: integer;
 buf: in_addr;
begin

 FHost:=inet_addr(PAnsiChar(FIPAddress));
 if (FPortEnd<=FPortStart)or (FPortEnd>32768)
 then FHost:=SOCKET_ERROR;
 if FHost=SOCKET_ERROR
 then
  begin
   if Assigned(OnWorkEnd) then
    OnWorkEnd(self);
   Exit;
  end;
 buf.S_addr:=FHost;
 FPort:=FPortStart;
 for i:=0 to MaxOpenPort-1 do
  with FSocket[i] do
   begin
    TimeOut:=0;
    FData:=Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   end;
 //
 while not Terminated do
  begin
   Application.ProcessMessages;
   InitSockets;
   if FPort>=FPortEnd
   then break;
  end;
 //
 for i:=0 to MaxOpenPort-1 do
  CloseSocket(FSocket[i].FData);
 //
end;

constructor TPortScanner1.Create;
var
 i: integer;
begin
  inherited;
  SetLength(FSocket,MaxOpenPort);
  if WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), FInfo)<>0
  then Halt;
  for i:=0 to MaxOpenPort-1 do
  with FSocket[i] do
    begin
      ATimeOut := 0;
      FData := Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
      if FData = SOCKET_ERROR
      then
        begin
        WSACleanup;
        Halt;
      end;
    end;
  Application.OnMessage:=ApplicationEventsMessage;
end;

destructor TPortScanner1.Destroy;
var
 i: integer;
begin
  for i:=0 to MaxOpenPort-1 do
    CloseSocket(FSocket[i].FData);
  WSACleanup;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TPortScanner1.InitSockets;
var
 i,time: word;
begin
 for i:=0 to MaxOpenPort-1 do
  with FSocket[i] do
   if (FPort>=FPortEnd) or (FTerminated)
   then break
   else
    if (GetTickCount-ATimeOut>TimeOut)
    then
     begin
      sa.sin_family:=AF_INET;
      sa.sin_addr.S_addr:=FHost;
      sa.sin_port:=htons(FPort);
      //
      WSAAsyncSelect(FData, Application.Handle, WM_USER+FPort, FD_CONNECT);
      connect(FData, FSocket[i].sa, SizeOf(FSocket[i].sa));
      ATimeOut:=GetTickCount;
      inc(FPort);
      if Assigned(OnWork) then
        OnWork(Self,FPort);
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      //
      //Sleep(TimeOut div MaxOpenPort);
      time:=GetTickCount;
      while GetTickCount-time<TimeOut div MaxOpenPort do
        Application.ProcessMessages;
     end;
end;

procedure TPortScanner1.SetMaxOpenPort(const Value: Word);
begin
  SetLength(FSocket,Value);
  FMaxOpenPort:=Value;
end;

procedure TPortScanner1.StartChecking;
begin
  if not Working then
  begin
    FWorking:=true;
    if Assigned(OnWorkBegin) then
      OnWorkBegin(self,FPortStart,FPortEnd);
    try
      Checking;
      FWorking:=false;
    finally
      if Assigned(OnWorkEnd) then
        OnWorkEnd(self);
    end;
  end;
end;

{ TPortScanner }

constructor TPortScanner.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FTerminated:=false;
  FPortStart:=0;
  FPortEnd:=MAXSHORT;
  FTimeOut:=5000;
  FMaxOpenPort:=500;
end;

function TPortScanner.StartChecking(const URI: string): boolean;
var
  s:Ansistring;
begin
  s:=getIPFromHost(AnsiString(URI));
  Result:=s<>'';
  if Result then
  begin
    IPAddress:=s;
    StartChecking();
  end;
end;

procedure TPortScanner.Terminate;
begin
  FTerminated:=true;
end;

end.
```

Использовать так:

```
...

  TMainForm = class(TForm)

...

    procedure Scan_OnWorkBegin(Sender:TObject; Min,Max:integer);
    procedure Scan_OnWork(Sender:TObject; Port:Integer);
    procedure Scan_OnWorkEnd(Sender:TObject);
    procedure Scan_OnPortChecking(Sender:TObject; Port:integer);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;
  Scan:TPortScanner;

...

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Scan:=TPortScanner1.Create;
  with Scan do
  begin
    OnWork:=Scan_OnWork;
    OnWorkBegin:=Scan_OnWorkBegin;
    OnWorkEnd:=Scan_OnWorkEnd;
    OnPortExists:=Scan_OnPortChecking;
  end;
end;

...

procedure TMainForm.Scan_StartBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with scan do
  begin
    TimeOut:=Scan_TimeOutSpinEdit.Value;
    MaxOpenPort:=Scan_PortsSpinEdit.Value;
    PortStart:=Scan_StartSpinEdit.Value;
    PortEnd:=Scan_StopSpinEdit.Value;
  end;

  if not Scan.Working then  // если сканер еще не запущен...
    if not Scan.StartChecking(Scan_AddressEdit.Text) then  // то запустить...
      with Scan_DisplayMemo.Lines do                       
             // а если ошибка попытки узнать IP адрес по URI была не удачная...
      begin                                           // то сообщаем об этом
        Add('Невозможно определить IP адрес '+Scan_AddressEdit.Text);
        Scan_DisplayMemo.SelStart:=Length(Text);
      end
    else
  else          // иначе останавливаем его (у меня была кнопка Старт / Стоп)
  begin         // название кнопки менялось по событию 'OnWorkBegin'и 'OnWorkEnd'
    Scan.Terminate;    // приказываем не посылать новые запросы           
    Scan_StartBtn.Enabled:=false;  //к нопка станет активной по событию 'OnWorkEnd'
  end;
end;
```

Можно и без проверок и по умолчанию количества портов и т.д.

Comment: упс... здається я не правильно зрозумів питання...